# Fetch GeoJSON once and display on different styles on Leaflet map?

Tags: php, leaflet, geojson

I want to add a province layer to Leaflet map, which fetched from 4 php for different UTM zones.

The corresponding sql table has promotion and population and density columns.

I want to fetch the GeoJSON layer once and display the provinces with different styles for each column values on Leaflet map with different names on legend.

then i have 1 multipolygon layer which i want to display in different styles for different column values.

Here is my full code for one case:

var ProvinceLayer = L.layerGroup();

```
// Fetch the GeoJSON data from multiple PHP files
Promise.all([
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone35.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone36.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone37.php').then(response => response.json()),
    fetch('Add_Province_Polygons_Zone38.php').then(response => response.json())
]).then(data => {
    data.forEach(geojson => {
        L.geoJSON(geojson, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return {
                                weight: 2,
                                color: 'white',
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.9,
                                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.population_density),
                                interactive: true 
                };
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                var popupContent = feature.properties.province ;
                layer.bindTooltip(popupContent, { sticky: true });
            }
        }).addTo(ProvinceLayer);
    });
});

ProvinceLayer.addTo(map);
control.addOverlay( ProvinceLayer, "layer1", {groupName : "group1"} );
```

I use this code 3 times to display in 3 different styles. Thus it affects the loading speed of web.

Have any suggesstion to solve in fact, fetched once and display in different styles on map?

Comment: Rather than run the same `fetch` calls 3x each you could store the results from the first batch and use that stored data?